# Is it intended that a BAC0 COV pings every 5 seconds even when there's no change?

Tags: python, bacnet, bac0

I'm using `BAC0.lite(port=XXXXX, deviceId=YYY)` to create a mock BACnet device on my network, including a few objects. As far as I can tell the specifics of the device don't relate to the observed behavior. I make a COV subscription using `bacnet.cov(address=XXX, objectID=(YYY, ZZZ), callback=my_function)` for one of the objects from the corresponding device.

It seems like when I change the object remotely, the COV does update immediately, but I also see updates every 5 seconds even when the state doesn't change. The updates are slightly longer than 5 seconds, which leads me to believe there's a `time.sleep(5)` somewhere leading to these notifications. I'm wondering if this is behavior I should expect when connecting BAC0 to a real BACnet device, or whether it's a factor of the device being a `BAC0.lite()` mock. If the former, is that intrinsict to BAC0 or would a integrating directly with BACpypes prevent the addtional calls? Also, is there any way to disable this if it is intended?

Comment: You probably need to also mention which client application that you are using.

Comment: I'm using BAC0 for the mock device and cov, not sure if that's what you mean by client application.

Comment: No - if your BAC0 mock device is playing the role of 'server', are you interfacing with it via what type of 'client' - a specific application or some client-base BAC0 code (?).

Comment: The client is a custom implementation using BAC0 and then I'm using the BAC0 client to create a cov subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set BAC0.lite(ping=False ...)

Comment: Please give more details on why this solves the problem.